# Richfaces - <rich:Editor> inside jQuery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, tinymce, richfaces

I use a `<rich:editor>` inside a JQuery UI dialog:

```
    <div id="helpDialog" style="display: none" title="#{messages.help}">
    <rich:editor id="helpTextArea" theme="advanced" value="#{helpUtils.test(helpId)}">
      <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons1" value="bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor"/>
      <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons2" value=""/>
      <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons3" value=""/>
      <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_location" value="top"/>
      <f:param name="width" value="90%"/>
      <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_align" value="left"/>
    </rich:editor>

    <p>
      <button id="editHelpButton">#{messages.edit}</button>
      <button id="saveHelpButton">#{messages.save}</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

When I click on "font family" or "font size" the dropdown box is shown in the upper left corner of the screen and not inside the dialog. (see screenshot)
How can I fix this?

[screenshot](http://rl-dev.com/tmp/scr000001.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put  to relative div (`<div style="position:relative"/>`) inside #helpDialog

Hope it helps.
Alexey.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it gives the same result.
Also tried tinyMCE config option `constrain_menus : true`

Comment: For the moment I can live with that.
Maybe I will put a button in the dialog for the user that has permissions to edit the help text and then use `<rich:modalPanel>` to open a new window with the `<rich:editor>`.
Because loading the editor is not that fast and most users only need to view the help text.